# why do I get a nullpointerexception while getting an excel cell

Tags: java, excel, exception, null

I'm getting this exception while getting a cell. This is what I'm doing:

```
if(versionToAdd.equals("15.6")) {           
    Cell X = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(28+j).getCell((short)7);
    Cell Y = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(28+j).getCell((short)8);
    X.setCellValue(x);
    Y.setCellValue(y);
}
```

this code it's inside of a for loop (j), and every time I iterate over a List of values, i get a new cell dynamically.

The problem is that, whenever it gets to the first col:row (H:29), i get a NullPointerException.

NOTE: The cells in the xls file are in blank... could that be the problem?

---

I got a collection of X/Y values in java, starts reading it, but whenever it reaches a certain amount of values, I get a NullPointerException in this line:

```
Cell cellx = row.getCell(8);
```

The java list is fine.
If I put less X/Y pairs (i.e: 5 or 6 pairs), works great, but over a certain amount (let's say > 10), I get that exception.

Tried looking for the cells, everything seems to be fine

---

EDITED: Thanks people for your help! I started to use the XSSF/HSSF from POI. Tried to use it before, but I couldn't get it to run properly, but now I did and it works perfect by using the createRow-createCell methods :)

Comment: If you want to debug this problem then don't chain method calls like you are doing. It will only make it more difficult to figure out which method call is failing. Put statements on separate lines and then the stack trace should tell you what is null.

Comment: it's a web application, don't know how to debug it haha :P

Comment: Ah ok, in that case try and extract your processing so it can run in a web app and non web app way. That will make your app easier to test :)

Comment: Hey Paul, i'm filling my code of Sysouts, to check variables. The problem remains while trying to get a Cell over a certain row number... for example, if the row number is less than 10 (for example), i can get any cells i want... whereas if is more than 10, i get a nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 1):

According to the POI documentation, if you ask for a row that is not defined, null is returned. 
The same is true for getting a cell from a row. I would assume that either a row or a cell does not exist.

Also, notice that the **short** version of **getCell** is deprecated in favor of **getCell(int)**

[POI Sheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getRow%28int%29)

[POI Row](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#getCell%28int%29)

You can use **getLastRowNum** to verify that the number of rows that you are expecting exists. Same it true for **getLastCellNum**.

If you are creating a sheet / row / cell, you need to use the create methods. Not the get methods.

[Create Row](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#createRow%28int%29)

[Create Cell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#createCell%28int%29)

The first three items on the user's guide are: how to create workbook, how to create sheet, how to create cells. You should check the documentation prior to posting questions.

[POI Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Comment: I know, but i'm not using HSSF anymore, since i haven't had anything but problems with it in editing-and-rewriting matters... i'm using this:

    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

Because of the WorkbookFactory.

Comment: In this manner all of the POI class work the same. The point is that you are assuming that either a row or a cell exists and it does not. You need to do some additional debugging to determine which assumption is incorrect.

Comment: But how do I create this cell, it needs to be created in order to set the value for X/Y coordenates.

Answer (score 1):

Both [`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) and [`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html) are `Iterable`. If you use the iterator in nested `for-each` loops, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077258/poi-wrong-date-formula-value-calculated/2079316#2079316), you should get only defined rows.

Comment: For Excel, "not defined" appears to mean that the cell is clear, e.g. `Edit > Clear > All`.