# Apply "formulas" to doubles in an array list of ArrayList?

Tags: java, excel

I have a table that I made by taking array list and storing it into another array list and it is composed of strings and doubles. Now I want to apply formulas to the doubles in the Table and I am wondering how to do this. And is there any way for them to update if the numbers in the table change ?

Comment: Any code to show? And how is MS excel used here?

Comment: I just save the excel file in csv = comma separated value and than I just interpret it as I like so any column wit a number is a number Only column. I asked if it is possible and how would I go about it I don't need a certain code for advice now do I ?

Comment: Well, it's a little confusing to me. When you say `And is there any way for them to update if the numbers in the table change` - you mean update if the numbers in the Excel table change? Thanks

Comment: yes like let say I have a row in which I had column one to column two so the row looks like this `1,2,3 ` and than I change the row to `1,3,4 `

Comment: @ashleysmith: re "*I don't need a certain code for advice now do I ?*": No need to get snippy. You're not obliged to provide code, but it would be helpful, because (even after reading the comments) your problem is still overall pretty unclear (to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) has an `evaluate()` method that may be useful in this context. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077258/poi-wrong-date-formula-value-calculated/2079316#2079316).