# Insert the Data in to Oracle Tables from Excel Sheet through JAVA

Tags: java, swing, oracle11g

We have requirement to insert spreadsheet data into oracle tables from Java. We have to insert the one sheet
data into 2 tables.

Below is the scenario.

Sheet Structure in the **.xls** file

Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6

A1        B1       10         5       80

A1        B1       10         20              AB1234

Now We need insert the data into two tables in database as explained below.

```
Table A

HID PID Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4

1001    2001    A1  B1  10  5

1001    2002    A1  B1  10  20

Table B
HID PID G_N G_V

1001    2001   Column5  80

1001    2002   Column6  AB1234
```

`PID` will be available only when records are inserted in Table A . With this reference we have to insert records into
Table B

We are making use of **jxl.jar**

Any solution will be a great help..

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of answer are you looking for? What is blocking you? Why did you tag this with Swing? This question seems overly broad to me.

Comment: What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: consider "loading ms-excel into oracle" http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ

Comment: @opi, you _can't_ load a .xls using SQL*Loader programmatically. You have to save it as a .csv first.

Answer (score 2):

In outline:

- Use [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) to open the `.xls` file as a `Workbook`.
- Iterate though the cells, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2079316/230513).
- Use [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) to populate the table based on the iteration resutls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use liquibase for this to insert data from .csv (Excel sheet).
You can insert data into any underlying database using liquibase also able to do the all database related operations through the XML. You just need to make configurations and write changeLog files which are in xml format.

```
<loadData tableName="A" file="com/sample/a.csv">
    <column name="HID" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <column name="PID" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <column name="Column1" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="Column2" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="Column3" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="Column4" type="STRING"/>
</loadData>

 <loadData tableName="B" file="com/sample/b.csv">
    <column name="HID" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <column name="PID" type="NUMERIC"/>
    <column name="G_N" type="STRING"/>
    <column name="G_V" type="STRING"/>
</loadData>
```

for more details : http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart