# Apache POI Date to String issue

Tags: java, string, excel, date, apache-poi

I'm using apache POI for reading excel.I have one date field in my excel file with date format as "MM/dd/yy". I would like to read all the cells as String. so I set all the cell type to string by using "**`cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);`**".  When this cell is converted into String the value i see for the date field is 41886. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The string `41886` measures time relative to the [Excel epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Instead, leave the type as `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` and use `DateUtil` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2079316/230513).

```
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the method `.formatCellValue(cell)` to return the formatted value of the cell as a String this method can be found in the `DataFormatter` class

more information in the documentation:

[DateFormatter (POI Documentations)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29)

Answer (score 2):

Dates in Excel are stored as a floating point value representing number of days (and fraction of day) since some epoch date (I think it's in 1900).  You need to read the date value as a date and do the conversion in Java.