# Get raw date value with Apache POI from a excel cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a excel with a date "30.08.2022", and this excel field is formatted as date.
But when I try to get a raw value i only get "44803".
No matter what I try I don't get the raw string. I just want to have the direct string.
I have already tried with  formatter.formatCellValue(cell); but then I get a formatted String value 8/30/22 . But I need the same value like in the cell

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    String excelName = "<path to exce>";
    String excelSheet = "<sheetname>";

    try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelName)) {

        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(excelSheet);
        XSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(0);

        //Date
        XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(0);
        System.out.println(cell1.getRawValue());//44803
        System.out.println( formatter.formatCellValue(cell1));//8/30/22

    }


}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you set German Locale using POI's LocaleUtil class?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a duplicate. I don't want to convert the date but just get the raw string 30.08.2022.. Since in the future all possible formats can be in the cell

Comment: Generally Excel stores everything in US format, and changes how it is displayed when the file is opened. What makes you think Excel actually stores your date in your specific format in the file itself? If you open the file in Excel in a different locale, how does it look there?

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817622/230513), the value 44803 is the correct number of days since the Excel epoch. You can use `getDataFormatString()` from the cell's style to obtain the format string used by Excel to display the value. The output below includes the formatted `Date`, followed by [the raw data : the data format index : and corresponding format string]:

```
Tue Aug 30 00:00:00 EDT 2022 [44803:59:m/d/yyyy]
```

```
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
    System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue() + getFormat(cell));
}
…
private static String getFormat(Cell cell) {
    return " ["
        + (int) cell.getNumericCellValue() + ":"
        + cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat() + ":"
        + cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString() + "]";
}
```

Conversely, given an instance of `DataFormatter`, you can format the raw date with the specified format, yielding `8/30/2022`:

```
var df = new DataFormatter();
System.out.println(df.formatRawCellContents(44803, 59, "m/d/yyyy"));
```