# how to get date cell value as it is from excel using apache poi (without formatting)

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

In my excel, I have  date like : [image]

but when reading it , it is printing as 11/30/22 , i.e it is printing in mm/dd/yy format but I need value as it is in excel cell, I tried different way but either it is giving in double or in this format.
Can you please help , how can i fetch the cell value as it is..

Below are few approaches I tried so far:

```
   DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
   Cell sDate = row.getCell(1);

   1) FormulaEvaluator formeval = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator((XSSFWorkbook) workbook);
     String startDate = df.formatCellValue(sDate,formeval);
     print (startDate);

   2) String startDate = df.formatCellValue(sDate);
     print (startDate);
 
   3) print ( sDate.getNumericCellValue());
```

Comment: try with `sDate.getDateCellValue();`

Comment: Try `getNumericCellValue()`, then use your preferred format string, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74816244/230513).

Answer (score 0):

> Excel stores dates as sequential serial numbers so that they can be used in calculations. By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,447 days after January 1, 1900.

[Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)

You have to format it by yourself.

Comment: No you don't, Apache POI will do the conversion for you - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue-- or https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html